# In OpenStack, what is the equivalent an Amazon AWS snapshot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, openstack

I'm an Amazon Web Services specialist. (AWS = Amazon's cloud computing platform.)

I understand the workflow for taking backups in AWS. What's the equivalent in OpenStack, and is it as robust? Here is what I want to do:

**Amazon EC2 Snapshot Process:**

1. On the server, freeze the file system or database.
2. Take a snapshot onto S3 while server is live. (Possible in OpenStack? How?)

**Amazon Restore Process:**

3. If system fails: Restore the snapshot. Amazon streams bytes of the S3 snapshot on-demand into EBS, so the system is sluggish, but service is back up in minutes. (Instant restore possible in OpenStack? How?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rough equivalent is creating an image form a running instance with [`nova image-create`](http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/nova.html#nova-image-create). This will take an snapshot of the VM and will make it available in the OpenStack Image catalog (i.e. glance). Then you will boot that image as if it was a normal image.

So you would do:

```
nova image-create <server-id>
(grab image-id from response)
nova boot --image <image-id> ...
```